# How can I generate thumbnails in GAE using GCS instead of Blobstore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am making an application in which the users can upload some pictures so that others can see them. Since some of these can be a bit large, I need to generate smaller images to give a preview of the content.

I already have the uploaded images in GCS, in urls with the form: "https://storage.googleapis.com/...", but from what I can see in the [Images API docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/), it uses the [blobstore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/images#Image), which I am not using (it's been superseded). How can I serve the thumbnails from the gcs link to avoid making the users load the full image? I would really appreciate any code example.

UPDATE:

I tried to copy the example with an [image](https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.trn-test2.appspot.com/TestContainer/Barcos-2017-02-12-145657.jpg) from my app using images.Image with filename as suggested, but it gives me a TransformationError, and a NotImageError if I don't try any transformations:

```py
def get(self):

    teststr ='/gs/staging.trn-test2.appspot.com/TestContainer/Barcos-2017-02-12-145657.jpg'
    img = images.Image(filename=teststr)

    img.resize(width=80, height=100)
    thumbnail = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG)
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
    self.response.out.write(thumbnail)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Those errors usually suggest a corrupted/missing image.  But the code looks OK, the file is visible, I'm out of suggestions...

Comment: As you can see in my post (image link) the image is there and it shows without any problems. Here is the link again: https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.trn-test2.appspot.com/TestContainer/Barcos-2017-02-12-145657.jpg so I don't think it's missing or corrupted. What else could it be?

Answer (score 1):

In general you can use the Blobstore API, but with GCS as underlying storage instead of the Blobstore, see [Using the Blobstore API with Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage). IMHO just the storage is superseded, not the API itself:

> Note: You should consider using [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/) rather than Blobstore for storing blob data.

For the [`Image`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/images#Image) class in particular (from your link) you can use the `filename` optional constructor argument instead of the `blob_key` one (which triggers the above-mentioned blobstore API + GCS usage under the hood):

> ```
> filename: String of the the file name of a Google Storage file that
>           contains the image data. Must be in the format
>           `/gs/bucket_name/object_name`.
> ```

From its `__init__()` function:

> ```
> if filename:
>   self._blob_key = blobstore.create_gs_key(filename)
> else:
>   self._blob_key = _extract_blob_key(blob_key)
> ```

Comment: I thought it wasn't needed at all, but I guess it's good I can still use that API. I still got an error while trying to use it like you just said, I'll update the question.